# MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) does not start

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, power, shutdown, repair

MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) does not start when i press power button. I was using the macbook and all of a sudden the laptop shut down and made some noise, ever since then, its been 4 days the macbook hasn't started. When i turn on the power button, nothing comes up on screen, the keyboard back light does not turn on but the fan spins. There is no chime as well. When i connect a phone via USB, it also charges the phone but nothing comes up on screen and no light on keyboard as well. I tried force shutting down, tried resetting the NVRAM, tried resetting the SMC but nothing helped. Also, when i connect my magsafe charger, the charging light turns green when it's fully charged and amber when it's charging. I have also verified that there is no issue with the macbook display as well. All the ports works just fine when i press the power button to turn it on. There is no issue with the magsafe and there is no issue with the battery as well. I have also tried my luck by disconnecting the battery by opening the backlid and giving it power directly using the magsafe but it did not work. Tried to remove the SSD for a few minutes and plugged it back again just to see if there is anything to do with the SSD but no luck there as well. I tried to get into diagnosis mode , recovery mode but nothing seems to be working. I also took the macbook to apple store, they asked me to pay them 3k INR (diagnosis charges + handling charges) and after paying the amount and waiting for 3 days unfortunately they had no answer for the supposedly "diagnosis" that they had done. I really need some help from all the brainies and experts out there.

Thanks a lot in advance. Hoping to find a solution here.

PS: I have never dropped my macbook, there is no water spillage. No short circuit. Absolutely nothing. It was working perfectly when i was using it and all of a sudden it shut down with some sound and ever since then, it just won't turn on.

Comment: You took it to a *real* Apple Store? If not, then that's your next port of call. You have a hardware failure, which the store should have diagnosed. It's not the kind of issue we can diagnose over the internet.

Comment: Yes. Obviously a real authorised apple store!

Comment: Then if they found no fault, what else did they tell you? They could quite easily have given it back to you with a virgin OS & said, it's fine… or they could give you it back not working… your question doesn't go into enough detail. BTW there's no "obviously", we cannot see over your shoulder, you have to **tell** us precisely what happened.

Comment: They told me to replace the logic board without any explanation and when i asked them for a diagnosis report where it shows that there is a failure at logic board level, they did not have it. I am not sure if they even diagnosed the macbook or not. Didn't want to really waste more money at the service centre so decided to get back my macbook. Their intentions were just to loot the customer.

Comment: Then report them directly to Apple. There's still nothing we can do at a remote to diagnose this.

Comment: I understand that this cannot be diagnosed remotely and I reached out here to see if somebody else faced the similar issue and may be they could help me with the solution which worked for them or someone who knows macbook could help me with their past experience and expertise.

Comment: Can you connect an external screen? What version of macOS is installed?

Comment: I tried to connect to an external screen but it did not display anything. The screen is working fine. It was running on catalina.